# Como reduzir o tempo de execução de uma query in SQL server?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server

Eu tenho uma consulta que quando executa ela esta demorando um pouco para trazer resultado. E eu não sei por onde começar para melhorar essa consulta. Se alguém pode me ajudar eu ficarei grato.

> A consulta copia registro que estão em uma tabela de referencia que
>   tem duas colunas (Nome de todos bancos e todas as tabela do meu banco)
>   e depois junta o resultado dessa tabela "**REFERENCIA**" para poder
>   inserir em uma outra tabela "**CONSULTA**" para listar todos os
>   bancos,tabelas,e outras colunas que se refere a essas duas colunas que
>   mencionei antes da tabela "**REFERENCIA**". Aqui está a consulta:

```
 /*INDICANDO QUE QUERO USAR O BANCO DADOS(OBRIGATÓRIO) */
use Dados

 /*DECLARANDO VARIAVEIS PARA MINHA TABELA RESULTADO QUE NÃO É FÍSICA*/
DECLARE @Resultado TABLE
(
 Tabelas nvarchar(max),
 data_sincronizacao date,
 rodovia nvarchar(max),
 elemento nvarchar(max),
 n_foto int

)

 /*DECLARANDO VARIAVEIS PARA MINHA PROCEDURE */
DECLARE @Table_cursor CURSOR 
DECLARE @rodovia nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @elemento nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @database_name  nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @sql_insert nvarchar(MAX)

 /*CHAMANDO MEU CURSOR,APONTADANDO ELE PERCORER A TABELA DE REFERENCIA A ONDE ESTÁ ARMAZENADO OS BANCOS E AS TEBALES COM TERMINO "ATTACH" */
SET @Table_cursor = CURSOR FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT Banco, Tabela, Rodovia, Elemento from Dados.dbo.Referencia

 /*LIMPANDO A TABELA "CONSULTA" PARA EVITAR DUPLICAÇÃO */
DELETE FROM Dados.dbo.Consulta

 /*ABRINDO O CURSOR PARA PERCORER TODOS OS DADOS DA TABELA REFERENCIA TRAZENDO DADOS DAS RESPECTIVAS COLUNAS */
OPEN @Table_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @Table_cursor INTO @database_name, @table_name, @rodovia, @elemento
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT 'Inserindo dados do banco ' + @database_name + ' e tabela ' + @table_name


    SET @sql_insert = CONCAT('INSERT INTO Consulta (Banco, Tabela, Rodovia, Elemento, n_foto, data_sincronizacao) SELECT ''', @database_name, ''', ''', @table_name, ''', ''', @rodovia, ''', ''', @elemento, ''', count(*) as n_foto, FORMAT (GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'') FROM ', @database_name, '.dbo.' + @table_name, ' GROUP BY FORMAT(GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'');')

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql_insert
    FETCH NEXT FROM @Table_cursor INTO @database_name, @table_name, @rodovia, @elemento
END
CLOSE @Table_cursor;
DEALLOCATE @Table_cursor;
```

Comment: Pode tentar usar o **Display Estimated Execution Plan (Ctrl+L)** e verificar se tem algum ponto que está consumindo mais recurso. Um outro detalhe é verificar os _Índices_ das tabelas, assim como definir um índice na tabela de retorno **@Resultado**.

Comment: @LeandroPaixão eu vou dar uma verificada. valeu pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente substituir o `CURSOR` pelo `INSERT` direto da seguinte forma:

```
DECLARE @resultado TABLE(
  banco              VARCHAR(MAX),
  tabela             VARCHAR(MAX),
  rodovia            VARCHAR(MAX),
  elemento           VARCHAR(MAX),
  n_foto             INT,
  data_sincronizacao VARCHAR(10)
);

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @query = ISNULL(@query + char(10) + 'UNION' + char(10))
              + 'SELECT ''' + r.banco + ''', ''' + r.tabela + ''', ''' + r.rodovia + ''', ''' + r.elemento + ''', COUNT(1), FORMAT(GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'') FROM ' + r.banco + '.dbo.' + r.tabela + ' GROUP BY FORMAT(GDB_FROM_DATE, ''dd-MM-yyyy'')'
  FROM dados.dbo.referencia r;

INSERT INTO @resultado
EXEC(@query);

-- Insere na tabela consulta
INSERT INTO consulta(banco,
                     tabela,
                     rodovia,
                     elemento,
                     n_foto,
                     data_sincronizacao)
SELECT r.banco,
       r.tabela,
       r.rodovia,
       r.elemento,
       r.n_foto,
       r.data_sincronizacao
  FROM @resultado r;
```

Comment: valeu mesmo. mais uma vez me salvou

Comment: Se baseando nessa mesma consulta, se for criar uma exceção tipo "if x tabela não existe, que não seja contabilizado" para evitar consultá com conclusão de erros?

Comment: @Gladiador aí complica um pouco mais a questão. Se você quiser pode criar outra pergunta com essa sua dúvida que eu penso em uma solução.

Comment: Entendido @Sorack

Answer (score 1):

Olhando a sua rotina dá para perceber algumas coisas que prejudicam a performance:

- Campos  do tipo nvarchar(max)

  No lugar de `nvarchar(max)`, determine um tamanho para o campo. Desta forma o SQL-Server pode calcular melhor o plano de execução.
- Campos do tipo nvarchar

  Se possível, substitua por `varchar`. Os campos `nvarchar` ocupam o dobro de espaço.
- Delete para limpar os dados

  Se não houver necessidade de manter o log e os campos de Identity, utilize `Truncate` para limpar a tabela Consulta, no lugar do Delete
- Cursor

  O SQL-SERVER sempre irá trabalhar melhor e mais rápido com conjuntos de registro do que com cursor (1 registro de cada vez). Pelo que vi desta consulta, este ponto não tem muito o que fazer, pois é realizado uma execução dinâmica dos inserts. Mas fica a recomendação para quando possível.

Comment: valeu meu amigo. Eu vou verificar isso amanhã e vou te dizer se deu certo ou não. :)